# Good configuration for 2gb (my.cnf)

Tags: mysql, configuration, ubuntu, my.cnf

I'm little newbie in configuring mysql and i seek a good configuration for mysql i have one site in ajax with many query and very slowly with VPS

Iam in kimsufi 2gb i run only mysql in vps not apache

This is a good config ?

https://gist.github.com/scottvrosenthal/5383554
Or http://www.t-scripts.com/mysql/

? Thanks

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.

max_connections = 1000


# Maximum allowed size for a single HEAP (in memory) table. This option
# is a protection against the accidential creation of a very large HEAP
# table which could otherwise use up all memory resources.

max_heap_table_size = 64M


# Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans.
# Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed.

read_buffer_size = 64M


# When reading rows in sorted order after a sort, the rows are read
# through this buffer to avoid disk seeks. You can improve ORDER BY
# performance a lot, if set this to a high value.
# Allocated per thread, when needed.
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64M


# Sort buffer is used to perform sorts for some ORDER BY and GROUP BY
# queries. If sorted data does not fit into the sort buffer, a disk
# based merge sort is used instead - See the "Sort_merge_passes"
# status variable. Allocated per thread if sort is needed.

sort_buffer_size = 64M


# This buffer is used for the optimization of full JOINs (JOINs without
# indexes). Such JOINs are very bad for performance in most cases
# anyway, but setting this variable to a large value reduces the
# performance impact. See the "Select_full_join" status variable for a
# count of full JOINs. Allocated per thread if full join is found

join_buffer_size = 64M


# Query cache is used to cache SELECT results and later return them
# without actual executing the same query once again. Having the query
# cache enabled may result in significant speed improvements, if your
# have a lot of identical queries and rarely changing tables. See the
# "Qcache_lowmem_prunes" status variable to check if the current value
# is high enough for your load.
# Note: In case your tables change very often or if your queries are
# textually different every time, the query cache may result in a
# slowdown instead of a performance improvement.

query_cache_size = 256M


# Only cache result sets that are smaller than this limit. This is to
# protect the query cache of a very large result set overwriting all
# other query results.

query_cache_limit = 128M


# Thread stack size to use. This amount of memory is always reserved at
# connection time. MySQL itself usually needs no more than 64K of
# memory, while if you use your own stack hungry UDF functions or your
# OS requires more stack for some operations, you might need to set this
# to a higher value.

thread_stack = 192K


# Set the default transaction isolation level. Levels available are:
# READ-UNCOMMITTED, READ-COMMITTED, REPEATABLE-READ, SERIALIZABLE
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED


# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.

tmp_table_size = 128M


# Additional memory pool that is used by InnoDB to store metadata
# information. If InnoDB requires more memory for this purpose it will
# start to allocate it from the OS. As this is fast enough on most
# recent operating systems, you normally do not need to change this
# value. SHOW INNODB STATUS will display the current amount used.

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 128M


# InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and
# row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to
# access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this
# parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it
# too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may
# cause paging in the operating system. Note that on 32bit systems you
# might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not
# set it too high.

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: I suggest you keep only one question. All 3 you have posted are similar and related to one specific problem - how to configure your `my.cnf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try MySQL Tuner which will give industry standard recommendations.

The link for getting started with mysqltuner is:

http://www.faqforge.com/linux/optimize-mysql-performance-with-mysqltuner/

You can download mysql tuner from here http://mysqltuner.com/